# possible to sort kendo grid.dataSource.data() ? NOT VIEW

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to update the actual grid.dataSource.data() sorting? not just the view ?

Normally you sort the gird like this:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
grid.dataSource.sort({field: "Name", dir: "asc"});
```

however this will update only the view not the actual datasource, is it possible to update the datasource as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that feature is not supported. To get items from datasource with order applied use:

```
grid.dataSource.view();
```

Instead of:

```
grid.dataSource.data();
```

Comment: I can’t use the view, because the grid is pageable and the view only has the data for what’s in the view of the user not all data

Comment: Could you also post your grid definition and dataSource definition aswell?